# GROUP BY date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored Procedure:

```
SELECT tsks.grouping_ref, ttg.description AS grouping_desc, 
SUM(ts.booked_time) AS booked_time_total, 
DATENAME(MONTH, ts.start_dtm) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, ts.start_dtm) AS month_name,
@month_ref AS month_ref

FROM timesheets ts
JOIN timesheet_categories cat
ON ts.timesheet_cat_ref = cat.timesheet_cat_ref

JOIN timesheet_tasks tsks
ON ts.task_ref = tsks.task_ref

JOIN timesheet_task_groupings ttg
ON tsks.grouping_ref = ttg.grouping_ref

WHERE ts.status IN(1, 2) --Booked and approved
AND cat.is_leave_category = 0 --Ignore leave
--AND DATEPART(YEAR, ts.start_dtm) = @Year
--AND DATEPART(MONTH, ts.start_dtm) = @Month

--accounting months 2012
AND (@month_ref = 81201 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2011-11-28' AND '2012-01-01')
  or (@month_ref = 81202 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-01-02' AND '2012-01-29')
  or (@month_ref = 81203 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-01-30' AND '2012-02-26')
  or (@month_ref = 81204 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-02-27' AND '2012-04-01')
  or (@month_ref = 81205 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-04-02' AND '2012-04-29')
  or (@month_ref = 81206 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-04-30' AND '2012-05-27')
  or (@month_ref = 81207 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-05-28' AND '2012-06-01')
  or (@month_ref = 81208 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-07-02' AND '2012-07-29')
  or (@month_ref = 81209 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-07-30' AND '2012-08-26')
  or (@month_ref = 81210 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-08-27' AND '2012-09-30')
  or (@month_ref = 81211 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-28')
  or (@month_ref = 81212 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-10-29' AND '2012-11-25')


GROUP BY tsks.grouping_ref, ttg.description,
DATENAME(MONTH, ts.start_dtm),
DATENAME(YEAR, ts.start_dtm)
ORDER BY grouping_desc
```

Essentially its filtering the results based on date ranges and then grouping the results like this:

```
Job Group | Month  | Booked Hours

   Test   | Feb 12 |    7
```

The user then clicks on Test where they will see a report on the 7 hours booked.
I would like to group by based on the date ranges?

I know that this creates the month:

```
DATENAME(MONTH, ts.start_dtm),
DATENAME(YEAR, ts.start_dtm)
```

But the group by date ranges should only show up if there are results, i.e Test might be in range 1 so it will show up otherwise dont show the date ranges.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not 100% clear to me what you're after. I'll give it my best shot.

I'm using a Dates table, with the month_ref and month_name your business uses. As you see, after you populated the Dates table, it holds all the data surrounding a date you will ever need. Use month_name in both the SELECT and in the GROUP parts.

Notice how much simpler the query becomes after using the Dates table.

```
CREATE TABLE Dates(
  TheDate       DATE    NOT NULL,
  month_ref     INT     NOT NULL,
  month_name    VARCHAR(10)
) 

INSERT INTO Dates(TheDate, month_ref, month_name) VALUES
('20120312', 81204, 'March 2012')

DECLARE @month_ref INT
SET @month_ref = 81204

SELECT tsks.grouping_ref, 
  ttg.description AS grouping_desc, 
  SUM(ts.booked_time) AS booked_time_total, 
  Dates.MyDisplayValue AS month_name,
  Dates.month_ref AS month_ref
FROM timesheets ts
  JOIN timesheet_categories cat
    ON ts.timesheet_cat_ref = cat.timesheet_cat_ref
  JOIN timesheet_tasks tsks
    ON ts.task_ref = tsks.task_ref
  JOIN timesheet_task_groupings ttg
    ON tsks.grouping_ref = ttg.grouping_ref
  INNER JOIN Dates 
    ON ts.start_dtm = Dates.TheDate
WHERE ts.status IN(1, 2) --Booked and approved
  AND cat.is_leave_category = 0 --Ignore leave
  AND Dates.month_ref = @month_ref
GROUP BY tsks.grouping_ref, 
  ttg.description,
  Dates.MyDisplayValue,
  Dates.month_ref
ORDER BY grouping_desc
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question.

After seeing

```
AND (@month_ref = 81201 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2011-11-28' AND '2012-01-01')
  or (@month_ref = 81202 AND ts.start_dtm Between '2012-01-02' AND '2012-01-29')
```

I remember how our code looked like, 2 years ago. You may consider adding a DatesTable to your database. In ours, we store all dates since the creation of our company till now and the dates for the next 20 years. Each day has a number of attributes (dimensions, columns, whatever you call them) IsWeekDay, IsHolliday, Quarter, YearNr, MonthNr, WeekNr, DayName, MonthName, ... you could add whatever extra columns your business requires.

Simply join the date of the activity with this table and select whatever dimension you need, like Quarter and Year. You can use those to group the results.

It took me less than half a day to Google some starting queries to get this table populated. We first made it for our datawarehouse, but now about every department is using it, to calculate pay-cheques bases on work on weekdays, Saturdays, Sundays, holidays; financial reports based on week, month, year, quarter, ...

It simplified our queries a lot.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with me. I know its good practice to create a seperate table. The issue is the group by?

Comment: My question is, how do group/display the date ranges rather than displaying the month.

Answer (score 1):

I second what Wim said because it is complete solution. If you are looking to patch up your current problem, you would be better off if you create a table of ranges and their names, join and group by range name:

```
select dr.Name ...
 ...
inner join date_ranges dr
  on ts.start_dtm between dr.StartDate and dr.EndDate
  and dr.ID = @month_ref
 ...
group by dr.Name ...
```

This way you will not have to change queries each year, and keep copies of them for previous ones.

EDIT: grouping by range

You want to repeat your filtering in group by. You are filtering one range only so you don't need group by for that. Put in select list something like

```
case @month_ref when '81201' then '1 2012' when '81202' then '2 2012' etc end.
```

If you want more versatile solution check start_dtm in case statement like this:

```
case when start_dtm between ... then '1 2012' .... end.
```

But then you will have to repeat it in group by. First solution I gave you would save you a lot of copy-paste and error-hunting.

Comment: I cant use the month_ref again, i will need to create a different name. Can you help me on the group by? Because the date ranges for the results are hard coded. This isnt actually the issue.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Could you post results you are getting AND what they should look like?

Comment: The results are in the original post my friend.
Job Group | Month  | Booked Hours

   Test   | Feb 12 |    7

Comment: Essentially Feb 12 is refering to date range 2 in my SP.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this: *But the group by date ranges should only show up if there are results, i.e Test might be in range 1 so it will show up otherwise dont show the date ranges.*. Could you please try to make it clear for me?

Comment: lets say there are 2 results, test and test2. test contains 7 hours and test2 contains 2hours. test was created on 2011-11-28 but test2 was created on 2012-01-02. This means 2 date ranges should show up.